# When this inequality true?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, gamma-function

If $a$ and $b$ are non-negative integers and $c$ and $d$ are non-negative real numbers, for what values is the following inequality true?

$\log((a+b)!) - \log(a!b!) \ge(a+b)  \log(c+d) -  (a \log(c) + b\log(d))$

I know that $log((a+b)!) \ge log(a!b!)$ and $(a+b)log(c+d) \ge alog(c)+ b log(d)$.